# Merging two data frames efficiently by common string values and numeric ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames

First

```py
data = [['chr1', 1,10,'Gene1','ID1'], ['chr2',15,20,'Gene2','ID2'],['chr2',21,40,'Gene3','ID3']]
LOUEF = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Chromosome_hg38', 'Gene_start_hg38', 'Gene_stop_hg38','Gene_name','geneID'])
```

```py
# LOUEF
  Chromosome_hg38  Gene_start_hg38  Gene_stop_hg38 Gene_name geneID
0            chr1                1              10     Gene1    ID1
1            chr2               15              20     Gene2    ID2
2            chr2               21              40     Gene3    ID3
```

Second

```py
data2 = [['chr1', 3,11,'location1'], ['chr1',11,17,'location2'],['chr2',20,30,'location3'],['chr2',15,17,'location3'],['chr5',1,19,'location4']]
cnvs = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['CHROM', 'START', 'END','locations'])
```

```py
# cnvs
  CHROM  START  END  locations
0  chr1      3   11  location1
1  chr1     11   17  location2
2  chr2     20   30  location3
3  chr2     15   17  location3
4  chr5      1   19  location4
```

Basically, both contained regions of our genome, the first are genes and the second deletions or duplication.

I want to map if my mutations are covered by the genes.

I have been using this code

```py
for key in ("Gene_name", "geneID"):
    cnvs[key] = (
        cnvs.loc[cnvs['CHROM'].isin(LOUEF['Chromosome_hg38'])]   
           .reset_index().merge(LOUEF, how='cross', suffixes=('', '_'))
           .query("CHROM == Chromosome_hg38")
           .query('START.between(Gene_start_hg38, Gene_stop_hg38) | END.between(Gene_start_hg38, Gene_stop_hg38)')
           .groupby('index')[key].apply(list).str.join(';')
    )
```

This is my result

```py
  CHROM  START  END  locations    Gene_name   geneID
0  chr1      3   11  location1        Gene1      ID1
1  chr1     11   17  location2          NaN      NaN
2  chr2     20   30  location3  Gene2;Gene3  ID2;ID3
3  chr2     15   17  location3        Gene2      ID2
4  chr5      1   19  location4          NaN      NaN
```

How could I do this more efficiently? I used `merge how=cross` but the dataframe created is massive. The result of the merge is 150*600,000

How could I do more efficiently? getting exactly the same results as this is one step in a process.

Answer (score 1):

I dont feel like cross join here is the way to go, as it will match every row from left df with every row in right df.
Here is my implementation, broken into 2 steps:

Step 1 - left join

```
df_merged = pd.merge(
    cnvs, # first df
    LOUEF, # second df
    left_on='CHROM', # column from left/first df (cnvs) to use to join
    right_on='Chromosome_hg38', # column from right/second df (LOUEF) to use to join
    how='left' # left join means that we will return all the rows from first/left df (cnvs) and only those rows fromsecond/right df (LOUEF) that will match
)
df_merged
```

[image: df_merges]

This look slike a typical SQL join.

Step 2 - group bt and apply

```
def custom_filter(x: pd.DataFrame):
    # filter ctireria
    gene_matched = x.START.between(x.Gene_start_hg38, x.Gene_stop_hg38) | x.END.between(x.Gene_start_hg38, x.Gene_stop_hg38) 
    
    return pd.Series({
        'Matched_Gene_name':';'.join(x.loc[gene_matched, 'Gene_name']), 
        'Matched_geneID': ';'.join(x.loc[gene_matched, 'geneID'])
    })

df_merged.groupby(['CHROM', 'START', 'END', 'locations']).apply(custom_filter).reset_index()
```

Final Result:
[image]

Let me know if this is actually faster and also if you have further questions.